# "Insert Image" popup appears behind the "Edit Post" model. Craziness ensues

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, user-interface, uploader

Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a post which has a suggested edit pending and hit the `edit (n)` link

   > [image]
2. Click the "Improve" option
3. Try and insert an image using the image uploader
4. You're still trying, aren't you!

... so yeah, the "image uploader" renders behind the model for the post edit, on Chrome 25.0.1364.172 on Windows 8 at least...

Comment: Reproduced on Mac Chrome, Safari and Firefox. After closing the edit dialog, the image dialog box is still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The joys of z-index and multiple popups.

I have increased the z-index of the image upload popups, so this shouldn't happen any more - the image upload popup will appear and you will be able to add an image...

To be with you on the next build.